# Content Divs below IMG with 100% width will not properly display below IMG

Tags: html, css, image, position

Issue: I am trying to make a layout with a fixed header for nag and below that will be an image that will fit the page. below that I want divs for content. the problem I am facing is that I cannot get both the image and the content divs to fit the screen and stack vertically.

The IMG is set to absolute because its the only way I could get it to 100% fit the screen without adjusting the margins. however when I do this the divs below that I am going to use for content: `.body2` and `.body3` do not show.

I want to get everything flush with the screen of the browser and stacked properly.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="headernav">

    </div>
</header>

<div id="FixedBKG">
    <img src="Images/imgbkg.JPG" id="bkgimg"/>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="body2">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="body3">

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#headernav {
height: 70px;
top: -10px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
color: white;
margin:0px auto;
}

#FixedBKG {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
}

#bkgimg {
width: 100%;
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
position: absolute;
}

.body2 {
background-color: #C0C0C0;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;

display: block;
}

.body3 {
background-color: black;
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle based on your code (some changes). Can you tell us what you want to do?http://jsfiddle.net/s5q5f/

Comment: On the fiddle, I want the grey and black div sections to be under the picture of the guy kayaking. i want those two div sections to have the same width of the IMG. currently the two div sections are behind the IMG and are not flush with the browser window's margins.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a second draft: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s5q5f/1/).

General comments:

1.Try not to use positioning on a straight-forward layout like this one.

1. I changed the image to `display: block` and made it 100% of the div width - it will then adjust itself to the container, and you can
   then adjust the container as you wish.
2. I changed the heights of the two lower divs and added a border so you could see them easier in the fiddle.
3. You really don't need the 100% widths, since divs are 100% by definition.
4. You might consider styling the body, and add a container element to give you more flexibility on formatting.

Let me know if you'd like to change anything else.

CSS

```
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#headernav {
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#FixedBKG {
  width: 100%; 
}

.body2 {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.body3 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid  yellow;
}
```